# How to return all the data in INSERT command from postgres using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

This query insert data into my users table in Postgress, however, some other data are autogenerated where INSERT command is used.e.g userId which is primary key, isAdmin is boolean but default is false.

How can i return all the data not just the inserted my data

```
e.g
const quertStrings = INSERT INTO users(email, first_name,last_name, password)VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);
const values = [email.toLowerCase(), first_name, last_name,  password]
try {
 const response = pool.query(queryStrings, values);
return response;
} catch(err) {
return error; 
}
```

If successful, userId, and isAdmin is auto-generated.  How can i return all the data both the *auto-generated and inserted data.*

Console.log(response); gives

```
Result {
  command: 'INSERT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: 0,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  _types:
   TypeOverrides {
     _types:
      { getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
        setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
        arrayParser: [Object],
        builtins: [Object] },
     text: {},
     binary: {} },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some things that may help:

1. Add returning * to the end of the INSERT statement.
2. userId should be auto-generated if you set it to serial.
3. isAdmin should be auto-generated if you also gave it a default value.

Goodluck!